# Сравнение итераций внутри цикла php

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, foreach, логика

Есть листинг постов с метаполями "Тип" и "Цена". Нужно перебрать посты и создать массив с "Тип" в качестве ключа и минимальной ценой в качестве значений. Что-то типа

```
$min_price = array (
   "studio" => "мин. стоимость студий",
   "1kom"   => "мин. стоимость 1kom",
   "2kom"   => "мин. стоимость 2kom",
);
```

Не могу разобраться, как выполнить сравнение текущей итерации с соответствующим значением в массиве и найти из них наименьшее. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $post  ) {
$type = get_post_meta( $post, 'rooms', true );
$names = array (
    'studio', '1kom', '2kom', '3kom'
);
  
foreach ($names as $name) {   
    if ($type == $name) {
        
    //  if значение $price[$name] существует, сравнить и записать в массив $price наименьшее 
        $price[$name] = get_post_meta( $post, 'price', true );    
}
```

}

Comment: заводите массив под результат, пустой. Идете по постам, получаете тип и цену. Если в результате нет такого ключа, то добавляете его с текущим значением. В противном случае сравниваете текущую и то что в результате уже есть, если меньше, то обновляете

Comment: по этой логике я и составил обход. Вопрос в том, как сделать сравнение, ведь $price[$name] и добавляет значение в массив и является уже добавленным ранее. Прошу прощение за очевидный для многих вопрос, я начинающий в php.

Comment: уберите вообще `$names` это что-то бесполезное. получили `$type` сразу же получите `$price`. не надо это пихать в какой-то массив сразу. Потом сравните `$result[$type] > $price`. Как написано выше, надо вообще узнать есть ли такой ключ в массиве вообще.